# Abrir archivo .exe en MacOS

Tags: vscode, macos, exe

Al momento de escribir este comando "clang -o Operaciones main.c sumar.c" se me crea otro archivo, tendria que ser .exe pero macOs no ejecuta estos archivos, como puedo solucionar esto para poder ejecutar el nuevo archivo, o que comandos debo ejecutar para crear un archivo verdaderamente ejecutable para macOS

Comment: `Operaciones` es el archivo ejecutable. En una terminal escribe `./Operaciones` y debería ejecutarse.

Comment: zsh: bad CPU type in executable: ./Operaciones
Pero me menciona este error

Comment: ¿La compilación la hiciste en `macOS`? Es decir ejecutaste el comando `clang -o` en `macOS` o simplemente trataste de correr el resultado de algo que se compilo en una computadora diferente.

Comment: Si estás en una computadora con Apple Silicon, intenta instalar Rosetta 2. `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -install-rosetta -agree-to-license`